# failed to create service fabric cluster on win-server 2012 R2

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I am trying to create a standalone service fabric cluster on on-prem environment, using Windows Server 2012R2. After I run the `CreateServiceFabricCluster.ps`, got the following error in the power shell windows

> System.Fabric.FabricDeployer.ClusterManifestValidationException:
>   Cluster manifest validation failed with exception
>   System.ArgumentException: IP address is not allowed for credential
>   type 'Windows' when fabric runs as NetworkService, please use
>   hostnames.

How to update the json config file?

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem, the Microsoft documentation seems not to mention this. I fixxed it by modifying the JSON so the iPAddress properties are the same as the nodeName properties like this:

```
"nodes":[
{
     "nodeName":"cl1m1",
     "iPAddress":"cl1m1",
     "nodeTypeRef":"NodeType0",
     "faultDomain":"fd:/cl1",
     "upgradeDomain":"UD0"
  },
  {
     "nodeName":"cl1m2",
     "iPAddress":"cl1m2",
     "nodeTypeRef":"NodeType0",
     "faultDomain":"fd:/cl1",
     "upgradeDomain":"UD1"
  },
  {
     "nodeName":"cl1m3",
     "iPAddress":"cl1m3",
     "nodeTypeRef":"NodeType0",
     "faultDomain":"fd:/cl1",
     "upgradeDomain":"UD2"
  }
```

After modifying the config just running the cluster setup again worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Inside `\SfDevCluster\Data` directory, you have `clusterManifest.xml` file. There you could change `IPAddressOrFQDN` property for your nodes and put there hostnames.

On a development machine, you can go to `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Service Fabric\ClusterSetup\[particular folder]`, `ClusterManifestTemplate.xml` and have this setting the same every time you deploy a new cluster.